# Why hide jwt token if it is visible in dev tools?

Tags: reactjs, jwt, google-chrome-devtools

There is a lot of talk about the importance of securing jwt token on frontend frameworks such as react, whether by hiding it in memory or storing it as an `httponly` cookie. But what is confusing is, why do all this when the token is visible in a request header to an API in dev tools?

```
Authorization: Bearer (token)
```

Is there a way to hide the token from devtools? Or are there other ways to handle this?

Comment: The risk and harms of token leakage via DevTools is negligible (or is even _desirable_, e.g. debugging/troubleshooting). Y'see, when we talk about "protecting" secrets/tokens/etc on the client-side (especially in the browser) we're talking about protecting those secrets from _other scripts_ (including potentially hostile and malicious scripts) loaded into the webpage (perhaps via XSS attacks) - **not** the browser's end-user.

Comment: _"Is there a way to hide the token from devtools?"_ - yes, but only by ensuring secrets/tokens _never reach the user's browser at all_ and instead you require the use of a 
trusted and securely-hosted reverse proxy to hold and manage end-user secrets - but doing so kinda defeats the point of an SPA.

Comment: JWT is simple to use, but hard to secure. Anyways, thanks for the feedback, it was very helpful.

Comment: _"JWT is simple to use, but hard to secure."_ - **eh, what?** ...hard to secure compared to...what else? **All** web authX schemes that rely on clients holding a _bearer token_ share this problem (this includes simple "API keys" and SAML). Now, there _are_ alternative approaches but they all have their own issues (e.g. Kerberos is LAN-only; NTLM is insecure and obsolete; HTTP Digest auth is a PITA; HTTP Basic and Cookies are both effectively the same as a Bearer token; Client X.509 certs are nice but 99.995% of users don't know how to use them and browsers make it unnecessarily hard too etc.

Comment: Haven't done a lot of research on alternatives to jwt, so never knew that. Thanks